# Reverse proxy with openid connect redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reverse-proxy, identityserver3, openid-connect

In my application I have integrated `Identity server 3` with `openid-connect`.
On our production server our website is behind a reverse proxy which is causing problems;

When the user logs in and is redirected back by identity server, our application wants to redirect the user to his original location (the page with the `AuthorizeAttribute`).
The problem here is that the user is redirected to the hidden url instead of the public url used by the `reverse proxy`.

How can I redirect the user to the public url?

Answer (score 7):

After a long search this is the fix:

The OWIN middleware `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` has a property `Notifications` in the `Options` property.
This `Notifications` property has a `func` `SecurityTokenValidated`. In this function you can modify the Redirect Uri.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "https://idp.io",
    ClientId = "clientid",
    RedirectUri = "https://mywebsite.io",
    ResponseType = "code id_token token",
    Scope = "openid profile",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    UseTokenLifetime = false,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
        {
            notification.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = RewriteToPublicOrigin(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
});
```

This is the function which rewrites the url to the public origin:

```
private static string RewriteToPublicOrigin(string originalUrl)
{
    var publicOrigin = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["app:identityServer.PublicOrigin"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(publicOrigin))
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(originalUrl);
        var publicOriginUri = new Uri(publicOrigin);
        uriBuilder.Host = publicOriginUri.Host;
        uriBuilder.Scheme = publicOriginUri.Scheme;
        uriBuilder.Port = publicOriginUri.Port;
        var newUrl = uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

        return newUrl;
    }

    return originalUrl;
}
```

Now the `OpenIdConnect` redirects the user to the public url instead of the non-public webserver url.